# Phonegap Cordova 2.3 clear the content of inAppBrowser

Tags: cordova, inappbrowser

Is there any way to clear the content of the inAppBrowser? Every time it pops up it shows the content of the last thing it had open for a few seconds until it finishes loading the URL I clicked on. 
I'd like to do something like set it to blank when it exits, so that it has a clean slate each time it opens.
I'm using Cordova 2.3

Comment: Something I am very interested in also.

Comment: Can't you just open some of your HTML pages ... ?? ... I think this will work ;) ... 
The local URLs are like file:///android_asset/www/index.html (for Android) ...